# SQL Computed Column: Convert varchar to time(3)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table which has a column `[Time]` that is of type `varchar(12)`. The column contains a time in milliseconds (example: `14:08:16.483`).

I also have a computed column `[TimeValue]` that should contain the converted `time(3)` of the string contained in the column `[Time]`, the purpose is to calculate the time difference in milliseconds between 2 records

| [Time] | [TimeValue] |
| --- | --- |
| 14:08:16.575 | #ERROR |
| 14:08:16.483 | #ERROR |

I tried the below formulas:

- `cast([Time] as time)`
- `cast([Time] as datetime)`
- `convert(datetime, [Time], 121)`

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2017

Comment: You can't compute column from multiple rows directly. You could create some function and use that, but usally this makes things slow and hard to understand. If you need such data only for reporting purposes, create just a view.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can use:

```
select cast('14:08:16.575' as time(3))
```

Of course this also works:

```
select cast('14:08:16.575' as time)
```

In SQL Server, you would use logic like this:

```
alter table t add col_as_time as (try_cast(col_as_string as time(3)));
```

The `try_cast()` prevents an error.

Comment: I need the formula for a computed column

Comment: The try_cast() worked!
Thank you for your support :)